# couchbase running in the cloud, ip address nightmare

Tags: cloud, couchbase

I have couchbase running up on a vm (azure), whenever i configure it to use an external ip or hostname, it won't start and i get an error in its log like this:

```
[ns_server:warn,2013-05-14T22:21:41.056,ns_1@[MYSERVER].cloudapp.net:dist_manager<0.280.0>:dist_manager:is_good_address:81]Cannot listen on address `[MYSERVER].cloudapp.net`: eaddrnotavail
[ns_server:info,2013-05-14T22:21:41.056,ns_1@[MYSERVER].cloudapp.net:dist_manager<0.280.0>:dist_manager:wait_for_address:100]Configured address `[MYSERVER].cloudapp.net` seems to be invalid. Giving OS a chance to bring it up.
```

if i use 127.0.0.1 , or the internal ip it starts up, but of course doesnt work because couchbase is such a peach about it's ip address'

Any thoughts?

Comment: (The IP address madness of Couchbase is indeed frustrating!) Have you followed the steps outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/16/couchbase-on-azure-a-tour-of-new-windows-azure-features.aspx) for creation a vnet for the couchbase servers?

Comment: I havent, i will though. I suppose i'll try a 1 node cluster at this point.

Comment: nope that made no difference, that doesn't really address the issue of accessing via external address. lots of questions in their forums, all with 0 answers.. boo.

Comment: ok, so now using the external hostname, with a loopback in the host file as per: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.ca/2012/12/what-to-do-if-your-couchbase-server.html (terrible post, but the facts were good0 and its running. jeez.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same eaddrnotavail error when configuring Couchbase server running in an Azure Windows VM. Tried the hosts file solution suggested in http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.ca/2012/12/what-to-do-if-your-couchbase-server.html (mentioned by Monsters X on May 15 '13) and it worked.

In short, just

1. Open the hosts file (usually C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)
2. Add a row "127.0.0.1  yourserver.yourdomain.com" (in Azure, it's yourserver.cloudapp.net) and save
3. In the initial server configuration (http://yourserver.cloudapp.net:8091), use "yourserver.cloudapp.net" instead of 127.0.0.1

It worked for me. My Couchbase server was running and can be accessed via yourserver.cloudapp.net:8091 (of course, you will also need to do: 1. add endpoint in Azure VM config, 2. allow incoming traffic on port 8091 in Windows Firewall in your VM).

Comment: Had the same eaddrnotavail error setting up a node on my local Windows machine (Couchbase server 3.0.3). This solution worked for me.